# How many process are created by the program?

Tags: c, linux, fork, child-process

How many processes are created by the program including the
initial parent process? Also how many times will “Hello” be printed?

I think, because it's 4 forks 16 processes (using 2^n), and parent process added to the 16 processes = 17.
(Not sure)

Here is my code below:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        
        if(fork());
        printf("Hello %d\n", getpid());
        
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: @JJF It prints out Hello 13 times, and prints the getpid() number with it.

Comment: And how many unique pids did you see?  That's the answer to your question, and now you just have to figure out why.

Comment: @NateEldredge There are 8 unique pids, and Is there a way to explain this by drawing a process tree?

Comment: Certainly.  Try drawing one, and for each process, keep track of the value of `i` at the time of its creation.

Comment: @NateEldredge So there will be 8 processes that are created including the initial parent process, and "Hello" will be printed 13 times.

Comment: In fact, I think that the code is not correct due to the extra semicolon (;) after if(fork()). Besides I think that the condition you should be looking for is "if (!fork())" so that the print executes only for the created child and not for the parent. Also re-check the number of times you think the loop is being executed.

Comment: @Ion Larrañaga I looked it up and it said that it shouldn't be a problem with the semicolon after the if-statment.

Comment: Not that it is a problem (the program runs just fine). It's only that checking the return value from fork allows you to distinguish the parent from the child, as in the parent fork() will return 1 while in the child it will return 0. This allows you to eliminate duplicates because you can make the printf to be executed only in the child, and thus only once per process (although in this case the initial process does not write anything).

Comment: Anyway, I may be overthinking it because you specifically asked for how many processes are created and how many times the Hello message is printed, so probably the question goes more about the number of duplicates....

Comment: @IonLarrañaga You're not overthinking it; you're exactly right. `if(x());` (with semicolon) isn't different from `x();` in any useful way. Compilers usually warn about that sort of thing, but people don't always read warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it, and it printed "Hello" 14 times.

I think the best way to solve this is by going backwards.
When `i = 2` (last iteration of the loop), there will be two prints of "Hello" - one of the parent and one of the child.

when `i = 1`, both the parent and the child will print "Hello" once each, and then each of them will continue to the next iteration where `i = 2` (and in this case we saw that there are 2 prints). So, in total, we have 2+2+2=6 prints of "Hello".

when `i = 0`, both the parent and the child will print "Hello" once each, and then each of them will continue to the next iteration where `i = 1` (and in this case we saw that there are 6 prints). So, in total, we have 2+6+6=14 prints of "Hello".

This can probably be generalized by some formula (and proved by induction).

Comment: Did you get 8 processes also?

Comment: @learning yes, exactly 8 different process IDs were printed.